# Return Absolute Value of a Google Sheet cell with AppScript

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, absolute-value

In Google Sheets, I'm trying to return the absolute values of a cell, using app script. So far I have the following code:

```
var SEARCH_COL_IDX = 1; // variable that indicates which column to search, 0 = column A
function SearchInventario() {

var ss      = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var formS   = ss.getSheetByName("EntryFrmMovimiento"); //Form sheet that captures data

var str     = formS.getRange("E4").getValue(); //cell that contains search criteria
var values= ss.getSheetByName("DataInventario").getDataRange().getValues();//Tab with dataset
for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    var row = values[i];
    if (row[SEARCH_COL_IDX] == str) {

    formS.getRange("C10").setValue(row[0]);
    formS.getRange("C11").setValue(row[1]);//This is the cell for which I need Absolute value
   }}}
```

It returns the data in the dataset fine, but I need cell C11 to then be converted to absolute value in this tab but not in the original dataset.

Any hits, tips or ideas will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Just for educatment purposes. You can make your own `Math.abs()` FUNction anytime:

```
formS.getRange("C11").setValue( row[1] < 0 ? -row[1] : row[1] );
```

```js
const abs = x => x < 0 ? -x : x;

console.log(abs(-25)) // = 25
console.log(abs(5))   // = 5
console.log(abs(0))   // = 0
```

Or even more funny:

```js
const abs = x => Number(x.toString().replace('-',''))

console.log(abs(-25))   // = 25
console.log(abs(-1.25)) // = 1.25
console.log(abs(5))     // = 5
console.log(abs(0))     // = 0
```

Comment: Many thanks for your contribution! I´ll be sure to try in out! Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
formS.getRange("C11").setValue(Math.abs(row[1]));
```

#### Reference:

- [Math.abs()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/abs)